# Joomla Development - Failed to move file

Tags: php, joomla

I'm having a strange issue with a component I'm working on. The component has a form that includes a file upload. The code checks for duplicate filenames and appends a counter to the end. All of this works perfectly except with I try and modify the record and change the associated file.

I used component creator to build the skeleton at that code works for updates -

```
//Replace any special characters in the filename
                    $filename = explode('.', $file['name']);
                    $filename[0] = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/i", "-", $filename[0]);

                    //Add Timestamp MD5 to avoid overwriting
                    $filename = md5(time()) . '-' . implode('.',$filename);
                    $uploadPath = '/var/www/plm_anz/' . $filename;
                    $fileTemp = $file['tmp_name'];
                    if(!JFile::exists($uploadPath)){
                        if (!JFile::upload($fileTemp, $uploadPath)){
                            JError::raiseWarning(500, 'Error moving file');
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                    $array['ping_location'] = $filename;
```

When I update the code to remove the MD5 sum and append the counter it all falls apart..

```
//Replace any special characters in the filename
                        $filename = explode('.', $file['name']);
                        $filename[0] = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/i", "-", $filename[0]);
                        $originalFile = $finalFile = $file['name'];
                        $fileCounter = 1;
                        //Rename duplicate files
                        $fileprefix = pathinfo($originalFile, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
                        $extension =  pathinfo($originalFile, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
                        while (file_exists( '/var/www/plm_anz/'.$finalFile )){
                            $finalFile = $fileprefix . '_' . $fileCounter++ . '.' . $extension;
                        }

                        $uploadPath = '/var/www/plm_anz/' . $finalFile;
                        $fileTemp = $file['tmp_name'];

                        if (!JFile::upload($fileTemp, $uploadPath)){
                            $fileMessage = "Error moving file - temp file:". $fileTemp . " Upload path ". $uploadPath;
                            JError::raiseWarning(500, $fileMessage);
                            return false;
                        }
```

I've narrowed down the cause to the filename that the while loop creates but cannot figure out why it only breaks the form update and not the new form submission.

The error I get in Joomla (3.4) is:

> Error
>
> Error moving file - temp file:/tmp/phpgwag5r Upload path
>   /var/www/plm_anz/com_hotcase_6.zip
>
> Save failed with the following error:

I know it's something simple but I've been staring at it too long to see it!

Thanks!

Comment: do you have all the permission to write in the folder ? What do you mean with "it only breaks the form update and not the new form submission"? so the first time works and when you update it doesn't?

Comment: I do have permission to the folder. I can submit the form and the files will upload as expected. The problem occurs if I click on a record to edit it and try to change the attached file.

Answer (score 0):

Ok as it is I can not see any good reason why is failing.

The only thing I can suggest you is that `JFile::upload` is failing go to debug in `/libraries/joomla/filesystem/file.php@449` and step by step try to understand what's wrong.

That's actually the file and line of `JFile::upload`.
In there probably the only line that matter to you is line 502 which is :

```
if (is_writeable($baseDir) && move_uploaded_file($src, $dest))
```

Especially try to see what's going on the variable `$ret`.